# File.CreateText / File.AppendText vs. File.AppendAllText

Tags: c#, .net, file

In order to use `File.CreateText()` and `File.AppendText()` you have to:

1. open a stream by calling either of those methods
2. write the message
3. close the stream
4. dispose the stream

In order to use `File.Append`**`All`**`Text()` you just use it and it will also creates the file if it does not exists yet.

I`m talking about .Net 3.5

Was there any reason to do it like the first above method back then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When we look at the [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,4ff1446b33bdfb6b,references) of `File.AppendAllText` we find that it is a shortcut, implemented like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true, encoding))
    sw.Write(contents);
```

The other methods open a stream and return it, and it is up to the caller to write to it, pass it on, etc.

It is always difficult to ask for the reason behind such a design decision. In this case it seems obvious: The "All" infix suggests that the caller would have a complete string that should be written at once, and there is no need to keep the stream open - it has been added for convenience, because that is a frequent use case.

To back this up, I have found this quote from [Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/DotNetBookZero10.pdf):

> However, in .NET 2.0 some additional static methods were added to the File class that make a whole lot of sense. These methods let you open, read from (or write to), and close a file, all in one statement.

Completely removing the previous methods in favor of the simplified ones would mean a loss in flexibility - developers will still have cases where working with a stream is required.

Comment: Thanks. In this case it was a simple write to log where I doubt anyone will change. I will change it hoping no one after me will change it back.