# Ways to make my .NET console application run faster?

Tags: c#, .net, io

I wrote a .NET application that's designed to take a large number (>10,000) of very small files from one directory and organize them into a directory tree that goes root/yyyy/MM/dd/file.name. The application works, and it's fast for smallish numbers (<1,000) of files, but the more files I have to move, the longer it takes. I'm a newbie at .NET and C#, but could something like running the move in parallel make it go faster? Or compressing the files in batches before the move? Ultimately, I'm trying to avoid problems with the program stalling or failing when the number of files to move gets too large.

This is the code I'm using:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace consolefilemover
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string rootDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rootDir"];
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(rootDir);
            string log = "auditlog.txt";

            foreach (string filePath in files)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                DateTime lastModifiedDate = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;

                // Create the destination directory path based on the last modified date
                string destinationDir = Path.Combine(rootDir, lastModifiedDate.ToString("yyyy"), lastModifiedDate.ToString("MM"), lastModifiedDate.ToString("dd"));

                // Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDir);




                // Move the file to the destination directory
                string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationDir, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
                if (!File.Exists(destinationFilePath))
                {
                    File.Move(filePath, destinationFilePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationDir, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + Path.GetExtension(filePath));
                    File.Move(filePath, destinationFilePath);
                }




                //Making a location for monthly audit logs
                string logfile = Path.Combine(rootDir, lastModifiedDate.ToString("yyyy"), lastModifiedDate.ToString("MM"), log);

                //Define the data for the log file
                string logInfo = Environment.NewLine + lastModifiedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + " | Source: " + filePath + " | dest: " + destinationFilePath;

                //Creates Log File
                File.AppendAllText(logfile, logInfo);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The moving of the file is done instantaneously.  The file isn't really moved.  The file has a start location in the file system and the location is moved from one directory to another directory.  What takes time is the locating the file and creating directories, and performing the GetFiles().  I would check memory usage using Task Manager while code is running and see if you are using all memory.  I think the reason code is taking longer is GetFiles is taking longer and using more memory.

Comment: Try [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-8.0#system-io-directory-enumeratefiles(system-string)). It wont read all files into memory at the start but read them one by one. You will also have to change the type of your `files` variable from `string[]` to `IEnumerable<string>` for this to work properly.

Comment: But I'm wondering what is the point of your program if you could just sort by modify date in the explorer?

Comment: Well, consider publishing your app in Native AOT mode will make an improvement in performance, as "one" option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by replacing `Directory.GetFiles` with `Directory.EnumerateFiles`. This will allow you to avoid large array allocation.

Then, create a `HashSet` of created directories and check it first before calling `Directory.CreateDirectory`. This will save you a lot of I/O if their values are repeated frequently.

Also replace string concatination

```cs
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + Path.GetExtension(filePath)
```

With interpolation

```cs
$"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)}{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}{Path.GetExtension(filePath)}"
```

To reduce number of intermediate string allocations.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to understand here is File I/O is stupid slow compared to other things you do in a computer. Even the new super-fast NVMe drives, which are about 100 times faster than the traditional spinning-rust disks, are waaaay worse even than things like exception handling.

Therefore anything we do that removes a disk access inside the loop — even just *tests* — can noticeably improve the performance here.

With that in mind, I see five places for improvement:

1. Enumerate the directory listing, rather than load it up front.
2. Load the `FileInfo` struct [as part of the initial read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles?view=net-8.0#system-io-directoryinfo-enumeratefiles(system-string)), rather than separately
3. Attempt to copy the file directly, rather than testing first. This assumes it's more common the destination file will NOT already exist. If it's more likely the file DOES exist, we then fail to save the disk I/O *and* still have a call stack to unwind. Act accordingly.
4. Pre-sort the data, so we only try to create a folder for each month/year when we first reach that month in the data set. (A Control/Break loop is good for this. It *looks like* nested `while` loops that would be Big-O of N to some bad exponent, but because it only increments in the inner-most loop it's actually just O(n).)
5. Write all the log entries for a month at once

Note the value of enumeration vs preload-to-array is reduced significantly with this plan, because you have to read the last item from the set to know where to sort it before you can begin (it might come first, after all). However, I believe the sort here is the more important factor, and the value of enumeration is not removed completely.

Also note the below code is typed directly into the reply box, and therefore almost certainly still has a bug or three to work through. But it demonstrates the gist of what you should do.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string log = "auditlog.txt";
    string rootDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rootDir"];
    var files = DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles(rootDir).OrderBy(fi => fi.LastWriteTime).GetEnumerator();

    // this uses what is known as a "Control/Break" loop, where the iterator only increments on the inner-most loop
    bool okay = files.MoveNext();
    while (okay)
    {
        int curYear = files.Current.LastWriteTime.Year;   

        // Setup for the current year (create the year subfolder)
        string destYearPath = Path.Combine(rootDir, curYear);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destYearPath);
         
        while(okay && curYear == files.Current.LastWriteTime.Year)
        {
            int curMonth = files.Current.LastWriteTime.Month;

            //setup for the current month (create the month subfolder and log path)
            string destMonthPath = Path.Combine(destYearPath, curMonth.ToString("00"));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destMonthPath);
            string logfile = Path.Combine(destMonthPath, log);
            string logInfo = "";

            while(okay && curYear == files.Current.LastWriteTime.Year && curMonth == files.Current.LastWriteTime.Month)
            {
                int curDay = files.Current.LastWriteTime.Day;
                
                //setup for the currnet day (create the day subfolder)
                string destDayPath = Path.Combine(destMonthPath, curDay.ToString("00"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destMonthPath);
                
                while(okay && curYear == files.Current.LastWriteTime.Year && curMonth == files.Current.LastWriteTime.Month && files.Current.LastWriteTime.Day == curDay)
                {
                    // Process the current record

                    // Move the file to the destination directory
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootDir, files.Current.Name);
                    string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destDayPath, files.Current.Name);
                    try
                    {
                        // *Generally*, you should not use try/catch for control flow.
                        // But in the case of file I/O, saving the extra trip to disk
                        // outweighs the cost of unwinding the stack.
                        File.Move(fullPath, destinationFilePath, false);
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex)
                    {
                        // TODO: we should detect if the exception is for 
                        // a reason other than the file existing and rethrow if needed.
                        destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destDayPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files.Current.Name) + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + Path.GetExtension(files.Current.Name));
                        File.Move(fullPath, destinationFilePath);
                    }

                    // Set the log message
                    // StringBuilder **might** improve this, but probably not enough to measure
                    logInfo += $"{Environment.NewLine}{files.Current.LastModifiedDate:yyyyMMdd} | Source: {fullPath}  | dest: {destinationFilePath}";

                    // increment the iterator
                    okay = files.MoveNext();
                } // finish current day
            } // finish current month
            // write all the logs for the month at once
            File.AppendAllText(logfile, logInfo);
        } //finish current year

    } // end of control/break processing

}
```

Thinking on this more, we can probably also achieve similar results via the regular Linq `GroupBy()` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string log = "auditlog.txt";
    string rootDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rootDir"];

    var months = DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles(rootDir).GroupBy(fi => Path.Combine(fi.LastWriteTime.Year, fi.LastWriteTime.Month.ToString("00")));
    foreach(var month in months)
    {
        string destMonthPath = Path.Combine(rootDir, month.Key); 
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destMonthPath);
        string logfile = Path.Combine(destMonthPath, log);
        string logInfo = "";

        foreach(var day in months.GroupBy(fi => fi.LastWriteTime.Day))
        {
            string destDayPath = Path.Combine(destMonthPath, day.Key.ToString("00"));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDayPath);

            foreach(var fileInfo in day)
            {
                // Process individual files

                // Move the file to the destination directory
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootDir, fileInfo.Name);
                string destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destDayPath, fileInfo.Name);
                try
                {
                    // *Generally*, you should not use try/catch for control flow.
                    // But in the case of file I/O, saving the extra trip to disk
                    // outweighs the cost of unwinding the stack.
                    File.Move(fullPath, destinationFilePath, false);
                }
                catch(IOException ex)
                {
                    // TODO: we should detect if the exception is for 
                    // a reason other than the file existing and rethrow if needed.
                    destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destDayPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name) + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + Path.GetExtension(fileInfo.Name));
                    File.Move(fullPath, destinationFilePath);
                }

                // Set the log message
                logInfo += $"{Environment.NewLine}{files.Current.LastModifiedDate:yyyyMMdd} | Source: {fullPath}  | dest: {destinationFilePath}";
            }
        }
        // write all the logs for the month at once
        File.AppendAllText(logfile, logInfo);
    }
}
```

Other than this, Windows is just bad for some reason at handling more than 1500 or so items in the same directory. If this helps you, I'm curious to know before and after run times.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to measure (for example using StopWatch) what is slow for huge number of files - getting list of files (in this case suggested change to EnumerateFiles) may help or file processing.

I think the file processing is slower, because of AppendAllText to log, again, this needs to be measured. If this assumption is correct - you can group files by year and process these lists-per-year in parallel, to avoid concurrent write to the log.

And in case or parallel processing all file operations should be replaced with async/await. Number of threads is always limited and this will allow to reuse threads more efficiently.

In case if there are many executions of File.AppendAllText for the same log (lists-per-year are large) - File.AppendAllText can also be optimized by opening file only once and writing new text to already opened file (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415206/file-createtext-file-appendtext-vs-file-appendalltext))

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can give **Parallel.ForEach()** a shot.

You can try if it improves performance, just keep in mind that for a small dataset a regular foreach is faster, due to the Parallel.ForEach() overheads.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/efa3cf/parallel-foreach-vs-foreach-loop-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Probably will not help, since this is I/O bound rather than CPU bound. Can actually make things worse on certain kinds of systems, where the parallel processing will cause disk thrashing.